# How to retrieve formatted version of date from date picker backend

Tags: c#, ios, date, xamarin, uidatepicker

I have a date picker and time picker I am using in my iOS application (using xamarin) and I am trying to retrieve the date and time selected by the user to use elsewhere in the code. My problem is that I am not sure how to retrieve just the date or just the time. For example I have this following code to retrieve the date:

```
// not getting proper date format!
var selectedDate = ContactDatePicker.Date.ToString ();
var selectedTime= ContactTimePicker.Date.ToString ();
Console.WriteLine ("Here: {0}, {1}", selectedDate, selectedTime);
```

But it outputs the entirety of the of the date and time for each variable like so:

```
Here: 2016-05-24 15:18:50 +0000, 2016-05-24 15:18:50 +0000
```

I would like to get something like `2016-05-24` for date or something like `15:18:50` for time. I realize I can use regex for this but I was wondering if there is a simple way to format dates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since [`UIDatePicker.Date`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoTouch.UIKit.UIDatePicker/) returns `nsdate` you could convert it to DateTime first and supply required format to `ToString` method.

```
var dateTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(ContactTimePicker.Date, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
var selectedDate = dateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
var selectedTime= dateTime.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: I have tried this method previously, but I get a build error saying there is `no overload for method ToString takes 1 argument`

Answer (score 1):

If `ContactDatePicker.Date` type is `DateTime` you can use `ToShortDateString()` and `ToShortTimeString()` or `ToLongTimeString`:

```
var selectedDate = ContactDatePicker.Date.ToShortDateString();
var selectedTime = ContactTimePicker.Date.ToLongTimeString();

//Output:
2016-05-24
15:18:50
```

According to documentation of [UIDatePicker](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoTouch.UIKit.UIDatePicker/), `Date` property returns a `NSDate`, but there are an implicit conversion to `DateTime`, so you can do something like this:

```
DateTime date = ContactDatePicker.Date    //Implicit conversion
var selectedDate = date.ToShortDateString();
var selectedTime = date.ToLongTimeString();
```

Comment: it apparently is not  `DateTime` as `.Date` does not have that function

Comment: thanks, I had to explicitly convert though. My output is still not exactly what I was looking for (`5/24/2016, 3:55:35 PM`) with your method but it's at least a starting point

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the info guys I ended up using:

```
// explicitly convert NSDate to DateTime to change format
DateTime date = (DateTime)ContactDatePicker.Date;
DateTime time = (DateTime)ContactTimePicker.Date;

// able to overload ToString() method with argument to change format
var selectedDate = date.ToString ("d");
var selectedTime = time.ToString ("HH:mm:ss");
```